# Changing paginator pageSize property doesn't refresh the table

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table

I am new to web development (Angular). I am trying to bind a `mat-select` display records option to with `mat-paginator` with the following:

**HTML**:

```
 <div class="col">
    <span class="">Display</span>
    <mat-form-field id="display-record-count" appearance="outline" class="mx-2">
      <mat-select [(value)]="displayRecordCount">
        <mat-option value="5">5</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="10">10</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="20">20</mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
    <span class="">records</span>
  </div>


<mat-paginator #paginator [pageSize]="displayRecordCount" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]">
  </mat-paginator>
```

**TS**:

```
displayRecordCount="10";
```

It doesn't work the way one would expect. It updates the item per page but doesn't update the mat-table.I am not sure what I am missing. Can anyone help me? I have tried the following:

```
 this.dataSource.paginator._changePageSize(+this.displayRecordCount);
```

[image]

See the code in
[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pkmssm?file=index.html).

Comment: I would change the question title to `Changing paginator pageSize property doesn't refresh the table`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just take change event for dropdown as below.

```
<mat-select (selectionChange)="this.paginator._changePageSize($event.value)">
...
</mat-select>
```

And No require to bind `value to displayRecordCount variable` anymore.

Checkout this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pkmssm-unc3p6?file=app/table-pagination-example.html)

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the paginator doesn't cause the data source to refresh just by changing its `pageSize` property, and calling `paginator._changePageSize` is required. You are probably doing it in the wrong place.

Add a setter to your property declaration to manually trigger a refresh, thus:

```js
  _displayRecordCount = '10';

  get displayRecordCount() {
    return this._displayRecordCount;
  }
  set displayRecordCount(value) {
    this._displayRecordCount = value;
    this.paginator._changePageSize(+value);
  }
```

Comment: It didn't work for me. Not sure why. could it be because my paginator is defined in `ngOnInit` like this `setTimeout(() => this.dataSource.sort = this.sort);`

Comment: If you make this change in your stackblitz it works. Not sure how your actual code looks tho.